# Find Closest Element in a Set

Tags: c++, set

Say I have a set, like such:

```
my_set = {"aaron", "cathy", "john", "stewie", "xavier"};
```

Say I want a function like such:

```
FindFirst(my_set, "a")      // returns an iterator pointing to "aaron"
FindFirst(my_set, "aaron")  // returns an iterator pointing to "aaron"
FindFirst(my_set, "bill")   // returns an iterator pointing to "cathy"
FindFirst(my_set, "zzzzz")  // returns past-the-end iterator
```

Basically, it takes a value and returns an iterator either to that element, or the first element after it (picking the past-the-end iterator if the value provided would lie after the end of the set).

Does any function like this exist in the standard library, or am I going to have to write one myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`set::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) is the function you are looking for.

Comment: Cool.  I skimmed the docs, noticed that one, and I guess I figured that it would return the first element in the set.  I guess that doesn't make sense since `begin` already does that, doesn't it.

Comment: It can't return the first element of the set in every case -- it returns an iterator to the first element *not less* than the passed-in element.